# Regular expression: extract and move a pattern within a string

Tags: php, regex, shell

I am trying to see if I can use a regular expression to rename a long list of files in a directory.

That is, the current file name is in the format below:

```
filename_[2013_05_30].mp4
```

And I'd like to rename it to the following format:

```
[2013_05_30]_filename.mp4
```

I am using Linux (Ubuntu) and can use either shell script or php.

Thanks!

Comment: [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Are they *always* 4 digit years, 2 digit months, and 2 digit days? Also, more importantly, what language are you using? Tag your question with the appropriate language.

Comment: Using PHP, you could split first by period, then split the first element by underscore, reverse, then rejoin all parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your files before.

Test with this line:

```
ls *].mp4 | sed 's/^\(.*\)_\(\[[0-9_]*]\)\.mp4$/mv & \2_\1.mp4/'
```

And when you are sure, add `| sh`:

```
ls *].mp4 | sed 's/^\(.*\)_\(\[[0-9_]*]\)\.mp4$/mv & \2_\1.mp4/' | sh
```

Comment: Thanks. I've gotten a much better idea through your response. I've used (.*)_([\d+_\d+_\d+]).mp4 as the search pattern and then $2_$1.mp4 as the replace pattern.

Answer (score 1):

here are a couple of different ways you can accomplish renaming files in a linux shell script(including regex) from unix stackexchange: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7161/copy-rename-multiple-files-using-regular-expression-shell-script

I hope this helps!